# how to access array of structure within a structure

Tags: data-structures, union

```
struct students
{
   char name[256];
   int Roll_number;
};

struct colleges 
{
   char name[256];
   Student students[100];
};
```

How to access student[0].name, I have tried to access using -> and . operator is is not accessable

Comment: Do you have any structs allocated? Or only these definitions? Show us the code that doesn't work. Also, as a future reference, add the programming language you're using as a tag.

Comment: What is the exact error message and the full code that demonstrates the issue? Is this a compile error or a run time error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Structure within Structure : Nested Structure**

1. Structure written inside another structure is called as nesting of two structures.
2. Nested Structures are allowed in C Programming Language.
3. We can write one Structure inside another structure as member of another structure.

as member of another structure

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct students {
    char name[256];
    int Roll_number;
};

struct colleges {
    char name[256];
    struct students students[100];
};
int main(void)
{
    struct colleges c = { };
    printf("%s\n", c.students[0].name);
    return 0;
}
```